# MPMoviePlayerController showing black empty screen does not allow to do anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am getting an a problem related to MPMoviePlayerController.

- Some time, When I play a video, its output is black screen only.
- Got message on console `unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: (null) MPMoviePlayerController`.
- App screen remains black even on app moved to background.

**Code:**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *videoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[prefs objectForKey:@"videoURL"]];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
[ self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[ self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
 self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: in which method do you add this code?

Comment: on button click event from UITableViewCell, and MPMoviePlayerController presented from its parent viewController via NSNotification Center.

Comment: I created MPMoviePlayerController object and present it on the View-controller. The blackout problem resolved.